# Assigning a letter grade based on results windows batch scripting

Tags: windows, var, batch-file

Currently i am working on a exercise and just need a push in the right direction to solve this.

The project is a six million dollar man quiz with 10 questions the exercise is to provide logic and assign a letter grade based on the number right or wrong currently ive tried

```
SET grade = 

IF "%right%"=="10" SET grade=A+
IF "%right%"=="9"  SET grade=B+
IF "%right%"=="7"  SET grade=C+
IF "%right%"=="5"  SET grade=D+
IF "%right%"=="4"  SET grade=F
```

at the end of the program it would echo the letter grade based on the %right%

```
Your letter grade based on answers = %grade%
```

I also tried

```
IF "%right%" == "10" (
     SET grade=A+
)
```

not working unless my problem is with set grade =

```
REM Define and initialize variables that will be used to track the total number 
REM of right and wrong answers
SET /A Right = 0
SET /A Wrong = 0
SET grade =
```

Comment: Please post a self contained script that fully exhibits the problem behavior. I am not clear on what you have tried or what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the experience that avoiding white spaces solves some problems as these are compared, too. So give this a try:

```
SET right=[Your logic]
IF %right%==10 SET grade=A+
IF %right%==9 SET grade=B+
...
ECHO Your letter grade based on answers = %grade%
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to give a grade based on the number of right answers. As long as that's the case, the answer to your question is no. If not, please explain what you mean. Also keep in mind that you'd need to write `SET right=%grade%` as grade is a variable.

Comment: Extra spaces do not cause problems with SET /A, they are stripped out. Extra spaces do cause problems with a simple SET - they are incorporated into the variable name and/or value.